# Populate a column on update (create too?), and why "FOR EACH ROW"?

Tags: oracle

I have a table of people who belong to various sites. These sites can change, but don't very often. So when we create an attendance record (a `learner_session` object) we don't store the site. But this has cause a problem in reporting how many training hours a site has, because some people have changed sites over the years. Not by much, but we'd like to get this right.

So I've added a `site_at_the_time` column to the `learner_session` table. I want to auto-populate this with the site the person was at when they attended the session. But I'm not sure how to reference this. For some reason (I'm guessing to speed development or something) the learner_id is allowed to be null. So I'm currently planning to do an update trigger. The learner_id shouldn't ever get updated, and if it ever did somehow, the entire record would be junk so I'm not worried about it overwriting it.

The trigger I have now is

```
create trigger set_site_at_the_time
  after update of learner_id on lrn_session
  begin
    :new.site_at_the_time:= (select site_id from learner who where :new.learner_id = who.learner_id);
  end;
```

which leads me to the following error:

```
ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers
```

Now, I've done some research and found I need to use a `FOR EACH ROW` - and **I'm wondering what exactly this `FOR EACH ROW` does - is it every row captured by the trigger? Or is it every row in the table?**

Also, will this trigger when I create a record too? So if I do `insert into learner_session(id,learner_id,...) values(learner_session_id_seq.nextval,1234,...)` will this capture that appropriately?

And while I'm here, I might as well see if there's something else I'm doing wrong with this trigger. But I'm mainly asking to figure out what the FOR EACH ROW is supposed to do and if it triggers properly. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FOR EACH ROW` means that the trigger will fire once for each row that is updated by your SQL statement. Without this clause, the trigger will only fire once, no matter how many rows are affected. If you want to change values as they're being inserted, you have to use `FOR EACH ROW`, because otherwise the trigger can't know which `:new` and `:old` values to use.

As written, the trigger only fires on `update`. To make it also fire upon insert, you'd need to change the definition:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_site_at_the_time
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF learner_id
   ON lrn_session
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT site_id into :new.site_at_the_time
    FROM   learner who
    WHERE  :new.learner_id = who.learner_id);
END set_site_at_the_time;
```

Comment: That was an oversight. The code sample was intended to illustrate the need to change `UPDATE` to `INSERT OR UPDATE`.

Comment: I had to make it `BEFORE` instead of `AFTER`, and I had to use a `declare current_site number(19)` and `select site_id into current_site from...` to get it to work. But this answered the two questions I really had: what was `FOR EACH ROW` and will my trigger actually trigger, and this answered them both. I appreciate that, and filling out more of the skeleton of the code block too! Thanks on all fronts!